# Missing space between author and page with biblatex-mla

Tags: biblatex, mla-style, sharelatex

I am trying to use [biblatex-mla](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-mla) to create a bibliography and cite works from it. Here is an example text with some citations:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
    @book{saussure,
        author    = "Ferdinand de Saussure",
        title     = "Course in General Linguistics",
        year      = "1966",
        publisher = "McGraw-Hill",
        editor    = "Charles Bally and Albert Sechehaye and Albert Riedlinger",
        address   = "New York",
        edition   = "3"
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=mla]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}



\begin{document}

While the horizontal axis (AB) depicts the coexistence of several entities at a specific
moment in time, the vertical axis (CD) additionally represents the changes of these
entities over time \autocite[80]{saussure}. By virtue of the complexity of the system of
language, it seems obligatory for the linguist to draw a distinction between the two axes
\autocite[81]{saussure}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the space between the author name and the page number is missing. I have tried to illustrate this in the following picture.

[image: Screenshot]

I am (and must be) running on [ShareLaTeX](http://sharelatex.com) – hence the `backend=bibtex` option to the `biblatex` package, as suggested by [their BibLaTeX example](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/bibliographies/biblatex/). I have tried to use Biber as a backend on my local machine instead, though, and got the same faulty results.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I run your document and I don't see the error. My system is TeXLive 2013 updated. What is your latex distribution? Probide a copy of the .log files to see the version of the packages. What I found strange is that I get different linebreaks.

Comment: Thanks for your effort @zunbeltz. I am indeed running TeXLive 2012. I'll try running the 2013 version. However, ShareLaTeX is running on TeXLive 2011 which seems to cause the trouble. Unfortunately there's nothing i can do about that :(

Comment: Yep, using TeXLive 2013 resolves the issue. I still have to figure out how to port this back to TeXLive 2011... Any ideas?

Comment: I think Texlive 2011 is using biblatex-mla version 0.9, and I think the problem is a (now-)faulty definition of ibidpostnote. Try redefining it in your preamble:

`\DeclareFieldFormat{ibidpostnote}{#1}%`

Comment: Hey @JamesClawson, i just found out the same thing and it fixes the issue ;-) Thank you very much for your help! If you like, you can post this as an answer and i will upvote and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Texlive 2011 is using biblatex-mla version 0.9, and the problem is its definition of ibidpostnote. Redefining it in your preamble will work (as you've already discovered! I'm slow, apparently.):

`\DeclareFieldFormat{ibidpostnote}{#1}%`

Answer (score 3):

I used a somewhat brute-force approach and copied [the entire .cbx file of the current version of bibtex-mla](https://github.com/jmclawson/biblatex-mla/blob/8c16a355629b3966a88b54194808259771d1a452/mla.cbx) to my TeX source surrounded by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. This fixed the issue. Then i started deleting lines until the issue appeared again and found out that i needed to add this line:

```
% fix missing space between author and page number in biblatex-mla
\DeclareFieldFormat{ibidpostnote}{#1}
```

Works now, thanks for all the hints and suggestions!